# Magento 1 : Show lowest possible price on catalog using custom options

Tags: magento-1.9, price, catalog

I am wanting to know the code to show the lowest possible price for an item as per their custom options without having to go into each item and make the lowest custom option price the default as this would be very time consuming for over 10,000 items.

eg. if an item has 2 custom options with varying prices then I want the calculation of the lowest price off the base or default price.

An example of this would be for smaller size but the smaller size is not the default option.

See here for understanding of product pricing. https://gilletts.com.au/a14064

1. base price = $2024
2. custom option 1 default =  Size T $0
3. custom option 2 default = width 5mm $0

But 2. custom option 1 lowest price is $ -378 for the smallest size.

I want the code to show the lowest price from the 2 lowest custom options.  so the price to show in catalog would be "from $1186"

**This is code for catalog only and not product page on CE1.9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone have a solution for this?  or direction to go